# How to join an unpivot resulting table with a dimension table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is my test environment

```
select * from dbo.fact1
```

| IdRecordRedcap | FechaRegistro | TotalPruebas | TotalPruebasPositivas |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-06 | 510 | 384 |
| 2 | 2022-01-07 | 300 | 184 |

```
 select * from dbo.DimMeasures
```

| IdDimMeasures | NameMeasure |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TotalPruebas |
| 2 | TotalPruebasPositivas |

So far, I'm able to run the query which contains the `UNPIVOT` procedure but I require to join it with `dbo.DimMeasures` so I can get `IdDimMeasures` for each `NameMeasure`

```
--UNPIVOT dbo.fact1
SELECT  u.FechaRegistro,
    u.NameMeasure,
    u.ValueMeasure 
FROM dbo.fact1 as x

UNPIVOT 
  (
     ValueMeasure
     for NameMeasure IN
     (
        TotalPruebas,
        TotalPruebasPositivas
    ) 
  ) AS u
GO
```

| FechaRegistro | NameMeasure | ValueMeasure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-06 | TotalPruebas | 510 |
| 2022-01-06 | TotalPruebasPositivas | 384 |
| 2022-01-07 | TotalPruebas | 300 |
| 2022-01-07 | TotalPruebasPositivas | 184 |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0c05808a6da3239dc023624a84c9b3fd)

Comment: Why do you have a "DimMeasures" table in the first place?  Measures are columns on a fact table, not rows in a dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  u.FechaRegistro,
        u.NameMeasure,
        u.ValueMeasure,
        m.IdDimMeasures
FROM dbo.fact1 as x

UNPIVOT 
  (
     ValueMeasure
     for NameMeasure IN
     (
        TotalPruebas,
        TotalPruebasPositivas
    ) 
  ) AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.DimMeasures AS m
ON m.NameMeasure = u.NameMeasure;
```

Output:

| FechaRegistro | NameMeasure | ValueMeasure | IdDimMeasures |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-06 | TotalPruebas | 510 | 1 |
| 2022-01-06 | TotalPruebasPositivas | 384 | 2 |
| 2022-01-07 | TotalPruebas | 300 | 1 |
| 2022-01-07 | TotalPruebasPositivas | 184 | 2 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b586bdf8fd8f9333035f2b0ec52b2072) (thank you for that!)